# proper way to clone repo I contribute to, postgres error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, github, pg

I'm a contributor to someone else's repository on github. I want to have the project run on my new machine

I pulled the project with:

```
git clone https://github.com/thebenedict/cowsnhills.git
```

and then run bundle and it's all gravy, but when I start the server I get the error

```
PG::ConnectionBad
FATAL: password authentication failed for user "cnh" FATAL: password authentication failed for user "cnh"
```

My pg gem seems to be installed alright. I used `sudo apt-get install libpq-dev` and didn't get errors.

If I do `git pull origin master` it gives me the appropriate "Already up to date"

It has never asked me for my github login credentials though. What can I do to run the server?

**EDIT:**

Okay I need to setup the postgres database on my local machine, the `config/database.yml` file looks like this:

```
development:
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  host: localhost
  database: cnh_development
  pool: 5
  username: cnh
  password: cnh
```

In the terminal I tried:

```
$ sudo -u postgres psql
psql (9.1.10)
Type "help" for help.

postgres=# create role cnh with createdb login cnh password 'cnh'
postgres-# \q

$ rake db:setup
FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "cnh"
FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "cnh"
```

What's the postgres command I need to run to set up my database given the above config file?

Comment: Have you set up PostgreSQL on your local machine? Have you added the appropriate db user and database locally?

Comment: Also, have you read through the entire documentation of the repo you're contributing to? There may be a special step needed to possibly add a password or something else.

Comment: oh no, I haven't set up the postgresql database locally. I have installed postgresql

Comment: check `config/database.yml` for the user credentials in the development environment. Create the specified db user.

Answer (score 2):

okay I'm really happy. I had to create a pg user, create database and update the user's role via

```
$ sudo -u postgres psql
CREATE USER cnh WITH password 'cnh';
ALTER USER cnh WITH SUPERUSER;
CREATE DATABASE cnh WITH OWNER cnh;
\q
$ sudo service postgresql restart
$ rake db:setup
```

Comment: Setting up PostgreSQL on Ubuntu (precise/12.04), Ruby on Rails : http://www.filippozanella.com/blog/setting-up-postgresql-on-ubuntu-precise12-04-ruby-on-rails-ror3-2-11-ruby1-9-3-and-heroku-gem2-34-0/